# How can I suppress only specific codes for specific checkstyle rules?

Tags: checkstyle

I'm trying to customize checkstyle checkers.

For example,

I want the MagicNumber checker to detect only constant 0 for all code patterns except for-statement.

'for statement' is allowed to use -1, 0 and 1.

Could you let me know how I can customize this checker or other checkers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Checkstyle checks can be customized in some way. The exact options (called *properties*) available vary by check. Each check documents its properties.

So, for instance, *MagicNumber* has [these options.](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#MagicNumber) Unfortunately, the properties you are looking for (to allow magic numbers in for loops; to detect only certain individual numbers) are not available.

In such a case, you must [write your own check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html), potentially as a subclass of the check you want to modify.

My personal recommendation is to use the MagicNumber check as-is, and fix all the magic numbers, especially those in for loops. But that's just me. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really need to create my own checker for our domain-specific reasones. For example, we have many 3rd party codes and we don't modify those for maintenance. So... I may add other related questions to create checkers after reviewing. Thanks ~~